# ヒアドキュメントで指定した改行を含むコマンド文字列を実行したい

Tags: bash

curl のパラメータを少しだけ変えたリクエストを何度も送りたいので
共通のコマンド文字列を定義して変更する部分だけ文字列を連結して実行したいです

具体的には

```
curl https://xxxxx
-d 'abc=xxxxxxxx'
-d 'def=xxxxxxxx'
-d 'ghi=xxxxxxxx'
-d 'jkl=xxxxxxxx'
  :
```

と言う20個ぐらいのパラメータの後

```
-d 'xyz=xxxxxxx'
```

と言うパラメータだけ変更して curl を叩くと言うスクリプトを書きたいです

なので前半部分を文字列変数(例えば$COMMAND)で定義しておいて

```
$COMMAND -d 'xyz=xxxxxxx'
$COMMAND -d 'xyz=yyyyyyy'
$COMMAND -d 'xyz=zzzzzzz'
```

みたいにかけるとスクリプトが見やすくなるかなと思っています

ただ前半のコマンドパラメータが量が多いのでできれば１行ずつ別の行に書きたくて
パラメータの中に ' も " も使ってたりしてエスケープが大変なので
ヒアドキュメントを使ってかけるといいかなと思っています

そこで以下のような ls と -l を別の行に書いて後から引数を追加して実行するような
テストコードを書いてみたんですがうまく行きません

```
COMMAND=<<EOS
ls \
-l
EOS

echo $COMMAND # デバッグ用　何も出力されない
$($COMMAND ~) # ls -l ~ が実行されて欲しい
```

ヒアドキュメントなしで

```
COMMAND='ls -l'
echo $COMMAND # ls -l が表示される
$($COMMAND ~)
```

と書いてみても

```
ls -l
test.sh: line 3: total: command not found
```

となってしまいます

どうすればやりたいことができるでしょうか

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) に陥っている気がします。 / 最終的にやりたいことが curl コマンドの実行であるなら、質問も別のコマンドに置き換えたりせず、実際の環境に合わせた質問文を構成した方がよいのかなと思います。

Comment: `$($COMMAND ~)` は `ls -l ~` の出力をさらにコマンドとして実行するので、そのような結果になるのは当然です。`result=$($COMMAND ~); echo "$result"` をしてみれば `total` とやらがどこから来たのかわかると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash のヒアドキュメントは文字列リテラルではなく標準入力として扱われます。
そのため記載されたソースでは 変数 COMMAND に格納しているつもりかと思いますが　COMMAND には何も格納されません。

エスケープが大変さがどの程度のものかわかりませんが、共通処理化したいのであればふつうに関数化するのはいかがでしょうか？

```
myls()
{
    ls \
     -l \
      "$@" ;
}

myls ~ 
myls /
```

Comment: bash に関数ってあったのですね　初めて知りました！　ヒアドキュメント使わなくて良さそうでスマートにやりたいことができそうです

Answer (score 2):

KTIさんが本来行いたいことは、

連続した引数リストの中からn個の引数を取り、それをパラメーターとしてコマンドを実行するを引数÷n回繰り返したい。

ということではないでしょうか？

であれば、ヒアドキュメントを使わずに

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    arg1=$1
    shift
    echo "count" \
    $arg1
done
```

結果

> count 1
>   count 2
>   count 3
>   count 4
>   count 5
>   count 6

一回のコマンド実行に必要な可変パラメーターが複数個の場合は

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    arg1=$1
    shift
    arg2=$1
    shift
    echo $arg1 \
    $arg2
done
```

結果

> 1 2
>   3 4
>   5 6

という方法もあると思います。

```sh
arg1=$1
shift
```

がキモで、これで、現在の引数の最初の一個を変数に保存し、引数リストからその一個を取り除きます（前に詰まる）

これにより、引数の先頭を望む意味の変数に代入し、引数リストから取り除くことを繰り返し、必要個数のコマンドに渡す引数を変数に代入し終えたらコマンドを実行し、引数がまだ残っている（処理したい対象がまだある）か？を判定する`while`で繰り返し実行します。

期待した回答でない場合には申し訳ありません

Comment: 確かに実行コマンド自体を変数化するのではなくループでパラメータだけを変更すれば、コマンド部分は直書きでもいいですね。ヒアドキュメントが使えないようだったらこの方針でいこうと思います。

Answer (score 2):

質問に対する直接の回答です。

【ヒアドキュメントの記述例その１】

```sh
COMMAND=$(cat <<EOS
ls \
-l
EOS
)
```

【ヒアドキュメントの記述例その２】
　`Bourne Shell`でも使える方法です。

```sh
COMMAND=`cat <<EOS
ls \
-l
EOS
`
```

【オプションを細かく分ける方法】
　ヒアドキュメントを使わずにオプションを細かく分けてもよいと思います。

```sh
OPT_A="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
XXX="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
YYY="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
OPT_B="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB ${XXX} ${YYY} BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
OPT_C="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"

OPTS="${OPT_A} ${OPT_B} ${OPT_C}"
COMMAND="echo"
${COMMAND} ${OPTS}
```

---

---

質問に追記された具体例の実装です。curlはダミーです。

【コード】

```sh
#!/bin/bash
curl(){ #dummy
    echo ${FUNCNAME[0]} $@
    return 0
}

xcurl(){
    arg=$1
    p=""
    p=${p}" ""-d 'abc=xxxxxxxx'"
    p=${p}" ""-d 'def=xxxxxxxx'"
    p=${p}" ""-d 'ghi=xxxxxxxx'"
    p=${p}" ""-d 'jkl=xxxxxxxx'"
    p=${p}" ""..."
    p=${p}" ""${arg}"

    curl ${p}

    return 0
}
xcurl "-d 'xyz=xxxxxxxx'"
```

【実行結果】

```
curl -d 'abc=xxxxxxxx' -d 'def=xxxxxxxx' -d 'ghi=xxxxxxxx' -d 'jkl=xxxxxxxx' ... -d 'xyz=xxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: `$()`(command substitution) ですが、[IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 Shell Command Language: 2.6.3 Command Substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) にある通り、POSIX compilent な shell であれば利用可能です。[dash(1): command interpreter](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) バッククォートに関して言えば nesting ができないので(バックスラッシュでエスケープする必要あり)、`$()` 記法をお勧めします。

Comment: はい私も`$()`の方がよいと思います。回答の表現を少し改めました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　やろうと思ったことはこれでできそうです！

Answer (score 2):

別の方の回答のように関数化するか、配列変数を用いましょう。コマンドラインの引数を含めた文字列を含む変数の展開は、変数展開後に行なれるワード分割とパス名展開がどう適用されるか理解していないと危険です。

配列変数の例を紹介します。

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ls_custom=(ls -l -d)
"${ls_custom[@]}" ~
"${ls_custom[@]}" /etc /var
```

参考までに、「変数に入れる文字列を複数行で記述したいが使用(変数展開)するときに改行は不要」という要件を満たす書き方もどうぞ。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="\
ls \
-l
"

$COMMAND ~
```